# Symmetry and Asymmetry of Linear Data Structures

Tags: java, data-structures

What does it mean to discuss symmetry and asymmetry of data structures? Particularly stacks, queues, deques and priority queues. My textbook doesn't talk about it at all and I've found mixed answers on Google. I'm just confused as to what symmetry of a structure is and I was wondering if anyone had any clear answer for me to work off of. Thanks!

Comment: In what context did you see this terminology?

Comment: The question is "Comment briefly on the symmetry or asymmetry of the linear structures stack, queue, deque and priority queue"

Comment: I've never seen the word *symmetry* used in discussion of those data structures before. It is not common language. It does, however, make sense to discuss *balance* in tree data structures.

Comment: When I hear symmetry in the context of data structures; it is usually synonymous with balancing. Like the original red-black tree was described as a "symmetric binary B-tree".

Comment: Ah! Priority queue is in your list of data structures. A priority queue can be implemented by means of a heap, which is a tree structure -- so symmetry probably means *balance*. The rest of those are not tree structures, so *symmetry* seems non-meaningful for them.

Comment: Agreed that symmetry is a strange term to apply to a queue or a stack.  Perhaps the question is alluding to the FIFO nature of a queue versus a LIFO stack.

Answer (score 1):

Double ended queues (deques) are symmetric, meaning whatever you can do to one end of the linear structure you can do to the other.   Stacks, queues and priority queues are asymmetric because you  are limited to what operations you can perform on the structure depending on if your are at the top, bottom, front or back of them.